# Chat one to one to integrate in website

Tags: c#, html, chat

Anyone knows an API or framework of an one to one chat to integrate in my website?

What i want, is create a chat, that enable a professor, talk privatly with his student. Actually i'm developing in c# and .net, html
Each professor have his students.

Can you help me?

Comment: Please take the time to read [ask] before posting your next question. Requests for libraries are off-topic on this site

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are ready-to-go Chat platforms for Web/JS that provide API, SDK and docs for integration.

I used [ConnectyCube](https://connectycube.com/) in many of my applications. They support Messaging, Video Calling and Push Notifications functionality for iOS, Android and Web.

- Javascript messaging (chat) guide https://developers.connectycube.com/js/messaging

They have ready-to-go code samples under MIT license for Chat in browser, it can be used as a start and save some development time https://developers.connectycube.com/js/code-samples

Chat and Messaging features supported:

- 1-1 messaging
- Group messaging
- Cross-platform
- Sent/Delivered/Read statuses
- ‘Is typing’ statuses
- File attachments
- Automatic push notifications to offline users
- Contact list
- Black list

The whole list of [supported features](https://connectycube.com/features/)